# Where to set locale in python while using django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, locale, django-i18n

My django app uses mixture of python's native `datetime.datetime.strftime` and django's `date:` filters.

Now, I can change the locale very easily in django using `settings.py`, but not so easily with python, because I would need to invoke `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')` somewhere during app startup.

Where should I put this code as it need to be invoked once during startup of django app.

AND is there any better way to handle such situation?

*P.S. I cannot do away with using python's native `strftime` because I need to serialize `datetime` object somehow.*

Comment: You should put that code in your `settings.py`, there's nothing wrong with that. However, I have a question for you: what if in the near future you need to support more than a locale?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini. Oh! Thanks for the quick answer. Yes, I understand the problem. Do you have any suggestion? As I said, I **need** to serialize `datetime`!

Comment: Well, generally when you serialize something, you want it to be locale-independent (e.g. you want to see `06` instead of `June`). I'm not sure what's the relationship between serialization and setlocale in your case, so I can't answer that question

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini thanks for the suggestions. I serialized my datetime object into iso string and then deserialized at the client end by creating a JS datatime object from the iso string.